# why this is not sorting by latest messages to be in the top

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT MsgCount.msgcount
    , c.userid
    , c.aspnet_guid
    , c.fname
    , c.lname
    , c.profileimagepath
    , c.profilealbumid
    , p1.msgdate
    , SUBSTRING(p1.msgcontent, 0, 50) AS msgcontent
    , p1.msgtouser
FROM dbo.userprofile AS c 
INNER JOIN dbo.usermessages AS p1 
    ON c.userid = p1.msgfromuser 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.usermessages AS p2 
    ON c.userid = p2.msgfromuser 
    AND (p1.msgdate < p2.msgdate 
          OR p1.msgdate = p2.msgdate 
          AND p1.msgid < p2.msgid) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
(
    SELECT msgfromuser
        , COUNT(msgfromuser) AS msgcount
    FROM dbo.usermessages
    GROUP BY msgfromuser
) AS MsgCount 
    ON MsgCount.msgfromuser = p1.msgfromuser
WHERE     (p2.msgid IS NULL)
ORDER BY p2.msgdate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try ordering by:

```
p1.msgdate
```

instead of:

```
p2.msgdate
```

This is only a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the data looks like in your table,  but because you have a left outer join to p2,  I am assuming that you are expecting that sometime there is not a value and p2.msgdate is null.  By ordering only by p2.msgdate ( a potentially null column ) you will not get the consistent results that you would get by ordering by a column that always has a value in it.  Perhaps ordering by p1.msgdate, or even coalesce(p2.msgdate,p1.msgdate) might give you more consistent results.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT MsgCount.msgcount
    , c.userid
    , c.aspnet_guid
    , c.fname
    , c.lname
    , c.profileimagepath
    , c.profilealbumid
    , p1.msgdate
    , SUBSTRING(p1.msgcontent, 0, 50) AS msgcontent
    , p1.msgtouser
FROM dbo.userprofile AS c 
INNER JOIN dbo.usermessages AS p1 
    ON c.userid = p1.msgfromuser 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.usermessages AS p2 
    ON c.userid = p2.msgfromuser 
    AND (p1.msgdate < p2.msgdate 
          OR p1.msgdate = p2.msgdate 
          AND p1.msgid < p2.msgid) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
(
    SELECT msgfromuser
        , COUNT(msgfromuser) AS msgcount
    FROM dbo.usermessages
    GROUP BY msgfromuser
) AS MsgCount 
    ON MsgCount.msgfromuser = p1.msgfromuser
WHERE     (p2.msgid IS NULL)
ORDER BY p1.msgdate, p2.msgdate DESC
```